# Awk: Using invert match to a string and then substitute characters

Tags: awk

I want to extract lines that don't contain `#` and delete `"`, `;` in the output.

My input FILE looks like this:

```
# ;string"1"
# string"2"; 
string"3";
```

Can use `grep` and `tr` to get wanted output:

```
grep -v '#' FILE | tr -d ';"'  
string3
```

However I want to use `awk`.

I can extract invert match `awk '!/#/' FILE`, but how can I use `sub` to delete `"`, `;` in the same `awk` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `gsub` for global substitution:

```
awk '!/#/{gsub(/[";]/,"",$0);print}'
```

The following transcript shows this in action, it delivers the same results as your `grep/tr` pipeline:

```
pax> echo '# ;string"1"
# string"2"; 
string"3";' | awk '!/#/{gsub(/[";]/,"",$0);print}{}'

string3
```

Note that the final `{}` may not be necessary in some implementations of `awk` but it's there to stop output of non-matching lines in those implementations (usually older ones) that do it automatically for lines matching none of the rules.

Comment: +1 for right approach. You don't need the `$0` arg in `gsub()` though as that's the default.

Answer (score 3):

Use `gsub` instead which would replace all matches not just one:

```
awk  '/#/{next}{gsub(/[";]/,"")}1' file
```

Output:

```
string3
```

- Skipping the third parameter to `gsub` makes it process `$0` by default.
- `/#/{next}` makes it skip lines containing `#`
- `1` makes it print `$0`

Comment: If you do the `gsub` before test for what line to print, you do not need the `next`.  See my post "Another awk version". Why do you have the `,` within the `[",;]`? It was not in the request to replace it, so can be removed.

Comment: @Jotne The complexity would still be the same and even more complex since you'd modify the global separator in general and even use `OFS=`. Also, you'd have more processing using gsub first before excluding a commented line since that would process the line as which is no longer needed. And that's actually the reason why I didn't do that. Thanks by the way. I made the update.

Comment: +1 for switching to positive logic (`skip lines containing #` instead of `select lines that DON'T contain #`) and so making the script less likely to incur double negatives if enhanced in future. Probably overkill for this but the general concept of trying to make things positive is usually good. The OP said `lines CONTAINING #`, though, not just lines starting with `#` so you could remove the `^`.

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` version

```
awk -F"[\";]" '{$1=$1} !/^#/' OFS= file
string3

awk  '{gsub(/[";]/,x)} !/^#/' file
string3
```

The `x` represents nothing. Could also have used `""`, but saves one characters :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give `sed` a chance:

```
sed -n '/^[^#]/s/[";]//gp' file
string3
```