# Pipe to AWK ignore line containing Unknown host

Tags: linux, awk

How could I tell AWK to ignore line that contains "Unknown host":

```
user1@ubuntu:~$ gethostip -d blabla | awk '{print $1;exit}'
blabla: Unknown host
user1@ubuntu:~$
```

Essentially, I want it to return nothing if "Unknown hosts" is contained in the line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Awk: Using invert match to a string and then substitute characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18941284/608639)

Answer (score 2):

Use a condition before the block to test the contents of the line:

```
gethostip -d blabla | awk '!/Unknown host/ {print $1;exit}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message goes to standard error, not standard output. If you want to discard it, redirect it to nowhere:

```
gethostip -d blabla 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $1;exit}'
```

If you want to process it, you can redirect stderr to stdout so awk sees both:

```
gethostip -d blabla 2>&1 | | awk '(/Unknown host/){print "Error";exit}{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply do:

```
awk '$0 !~ /Unknown host/'
```